# Cómo incluir dos ListView.builder dentro de un solo Scroll en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-listview

Estoy haciendo una lista de tareas (TODO) muy sencilla y quiero dividirla en dos grupos> las tareas pendientes arriba y las tareas completadas abajo marcando un título que las separe claramente.

Para este efecto generé dos listas (_pendientesList y _completasList) y a cada una le puse un ListView.builder, sin embargo al desplegar el Column se observa un primer Scroll de _completasList, después el Texto de "Completas" y después un segundo Scroll de _pendientesList. Lo que quisiera lograr es que los tres componentes hagan parte de un mismo Scroll.

El código para generar el listado desde un StreamBuilder es el siguiente:

```
Widget _crearListado(BuildContext context, AlarmaBloc alarmaBloc) {

    final _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    List<AlarmaModel> _completasList = new List();
    List<AlarmaModel> _pendientesList = new List();

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: _size.height * 0.5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70.0/2, left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top:0.0), //fondo gris del listado. Bottom
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: alarmaBloc.alarmasStream,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AlarmaModel>> snapshot){
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final tareasList = snapshot.data;
                    if (tareasList.length == 0) return _imagenInicial(context);
                    tareasList.sort((a, b) => a.fechaVencimiento.compareTo(b.fechaVencimiento));
                    _completasList = tareasList.where((element) => element.completa==true).toList();
                    _pendientesList = tareasList.where((element) => element.completa==false).toList();


                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(


                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: _pendientesList.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, i) =>_crearItem(context, alarmaBloc, _pendientesList[i]),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 20.0),
                            ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0,),

                        Text('Completas  '),

                        Expanded(


                          child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: _completasList.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, i) =>_crearItem(context, alarmaBloc, _completasList[i]),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 20.0),
                            ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                  } 
                    return Center (child: Image(image: AssetImage('Preloader.gif'), height: 200.0,));
                },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Intenté envolver el Column en un SingleChildScrollView, pero no funcionó.

**Cómo puedo tener los dos ListView.builder y el texto (o botón en el futuro) dentro del mismo Scroll?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de varias formas, con slivers o también sin, te pongo el ejemplo sin slivers:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemExtent: 100,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    child: Text(
                      index.toString(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text('Completas', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,),
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemExtent: 100,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    child: Text(
                      index.toString(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

La idea principal es usar un `Column` con un `SingleChildScrollView` para que haga scroll, luego 2 listas dentro con `shrinkWrap: true`, luego le cambias la física a `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`. Es todo.

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]